# Getting WebDriverException: Message: Unhandled endpoint when executing script with scroll or swipe keywords (Appium library) on iOS real device

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, robotframework, appium-ios

I'm using Robot Framework with Appium Library for test scripts for native iOS application on Real Device.

I need to scroll down (or up) to certain elements on the screen that aren't visible into view, but when I'm using the keywords **scroll, scroll down, scroll up** with appropriate element locators, or **swipe** and **swipe by percent**, I'm getting the same error when executing the script:

> WebDriverException: Message: Unhandled endpoint: /session/[SESSION
> ID]/execute -- http://[IP]:8100/ with parameters {
> wildcards =     (
> "session/[SESSION ID]/execute"
> ); }

Additionally I tried by using javascript, but without success i.e. the same error appears:

```
Execute Script  driver.execute('mobile: scroll', {direction: 'down'});
```

Does anyone have an idea what causes this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function:

This work for me handle swipe for iOS application:
I'm using appium 1.21.0

```
public void swipeScreen(String direction) {
        int deviceWidth = getDriver().manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
        int deviceHeight = getDriver().manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
        int midX = (deviceWidth / 2);
        int midY = (deviceHeight / 2);
        int bottomEdge = (int) (deviceHeight * 0.85f);

        Dimension size = getDriver().manage().window().getSize();
        int y0 = (int)((double)size.height * 0.7D);
        int y1 = (int)((double)size.height * 0.3D);

        switch (direction.toUpperCase()) {
            case "DOWN":
                new TouchAction(getDriver())
                        .press(PointOption.point(midX, midY))
                        .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
                        .moveTo(PointOption.point(midX, bottomEdge))
                        .release()
                        .perform();
                waitABit(2);
                break;
            case "UP":
                new TouchAction(getDriver())
                        .press((new PointOption()).withCoordinates(midX, y0))
                        .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
                        .moveTo((new PointOption()).withCoordinates(midX, y1))
                        .release()
                        .perform();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + direction.toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    public void swipeUpScreenToElement(By element) {
        for(int i = 0; i < getExplicitTimeout(); ++i) {
            if (!isPresent(element)) {
                swipeScreen("UP");
            }
        }
    }

    public void swipeDownScreenToElement(By element, int swipeCount) {
        for(int i = 0; i < getExplicitTimeout(); ++i) {
            if (!isPresent(element)) {
                swipeScreen("DOWN");
            }
        }
    }
```